# navbar load in all html page without refresh each page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i make navbar html page that contain navbar i want to load it in all my page

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="navbar-title"></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">eLibrary</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="add-book.html">Add Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-book.html">View Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Issue Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">View Issued Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Return Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

i make js file for each page and load navbar on it , it's work correctly but the problem is in navigation , when i navigate form item to another item its virtually load the page of clicked item but it's seem that the page refresh , i want navbar To be present immediately how can i make that ??

Comment: Look for SPA | Web Components

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing, but I think you mean you want to load the content which the menu items refer to without refreshing the page? In that case look into using AJAX to fetch the relevant content when the menu items are clicked.